# Best way to call AWS Lambda in C++?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda and am creating a simple C++ application to call it.

Based on the AWS Docs, I went and installed the SDK here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp but that seems to add nearly a full GB if I include the whole thing.

Is there something like boto3 for C++?

If not, what is the accepted best way of integrating Lambda calls into a small C++ application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something like boto3 for C++?

That's literally the thing you linked to. Boto3 is the AWS SDK for Python. This is the AWS SDK for C++.

What you are missing is that you can [install just the packages you need](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/setup-linux-vcpkg.html) from the SDK, instead of the full SDK.